# How to specify Spring in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring, puma

When issuing the command `rails s -e development` my Windows machine tries to start a PUMA server. I currently have the gem for PUMA being installed in production and Spring in development. How can I run my development testing using spring while still using PUMA for production?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. When asking a question it's important to format your question for readability using proper grammar. It helps us read and understand what you're asking, which speeds up the answers you'll get. In other words, put in the effort to ask your question clearly, which helps us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking about. [Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma) is a web server to server your application. [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) is a preloader to make application related commands faster. Take a look at the [`setup` section of Spring's readme file](https://github.com/rails/spring#walkthrough) to learn how to use it.

To use Puma only in production, you can put it in the [`production` group in your Gemfile](http://bundler.io/groups.html). In such case, Rails will fallback to default web server. Note that you should have it in your Gemfile's depencencies (for example by adding the gem into `development` group). Depending on framework version it can be Webrick or Puma in the most recent one.